# Sending messages ( JMS ) on a UDQ with single port targetting

Tags: proxy, weblogic, cluster-computing

I have a JMS setup as below :

```
*  1 Admin Server - AdminServer  
*  2 Managed servers - managed_server1 , managed_server2  
*  2 JMS servers - jms_server1 , jms_server2  
*  1 UDQ - UDQ
*  1 Connection Factory - UDQ_CF
*  1 Cluster ( managed_server1 & managed_server2 )
```

Targeting is done as :

```
jms_server1 and Store1 => managed_server1  
jms_server2 and Store2 => managed_server2  
JMS_Module => Cluster  
SubDeployment_UDQ => jms_server1, jms_server1  
ConnFacty (with "affinity disabled") => Cluster  
UDQ => SubDeployment_UDQ
```

I have an upstream component that will post a JMS message on my UDQ and my wls setup will take care of the load balancing , the problem is - For this component to send message on my UDQ , it has to set the URL as  :

```
ipaddress:managed_server1_port ; ipaddress:managed_server2_port
```

I don't want this kind of targeting because in future if I have to increase the number of managed servers in my environment upstream component will be impacted. Moreover , What if my domain has 100 managed servers ? I cant keep adding all of these details in the URL

Is there a more practical , seamless solution available to this problem ?
I explored setting up an httpproxy but that wont help in this setup where no GUI /  http requests are to be handled.

Thanks for your help / inputs in advance
Bhavin Bhatia

Comment: PS : UDQ is Uniform distributed Queue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Friends ,

One crude way of doing it was by creating a local Bridge between a Queue (details of which can be shared with the upstream component) and the UDQ as the target destination.

Not a very good way of doing it I know , but that's the only way forward I see if multiple ports are not to be shared with everyone.

Please post your comments / suggestions on this approach and if there's any other better way of doing it.

Bhavin

Answer (score 0):

In this case your options are limited (if its not http/webservice interface).

You can use DNS server (domain name system) which would map multiple `ipaddress:managed_server1_port ; ipaddress:managed_server2_port` to single `host:port`, between upstream component and your weblogic domain.

In this case DNS server would required to be modified when you add new managed server but not the upstream component/client.

Comment: Sad to hear that :( Weblogic should be giving this feature by default. Does any other app server give this capability ?